# Salesforce: QueryResult must start with '{'

Tags: apex

I had some logic on Lightning app where some Model record is passed from Apex Controller to Lightning app and then back to Apex Controller.

Today it started failed on the line

```
JSON.deserialize( jsonPM, Model.class );
```

with very strange and misleading error

> System.JSONException: QueryResult must start with '{'

Looks like there are some problems if you are trying to serialize and deserialize a complex model which consist of record of Object A with related record of Object B type which has related children of Object C type with parents.

```
{
    "lookupToB__c": "bbb000000-id",
    "lookupToB__r": {
            "Id": "bbb000000-id",
            "Name": "Big B - record 1",
            "children_C__r": [{
                "lookupToB__c": "bbb000000-id",
                "Id": "ccc-----id"
            }, {
                "lookupToB__c": "bbb000000-id",
                "Id": "ccc---1-id"
            }]
        } 
}
```

**How can I avoid this error, and why is it cropping up when I include both `lookupToB__c` and `lookupToB__r`?**

Comment: Does this have a question?

Comment: As you said, it is failing today. Was it working before?

Comment: it didn't have to lookupToB__r

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman: There were actually several questions. One question is how to avoid this error. I think I have already found an answer to the first question. Another question is why a heck it is happening when it should not. No answer to the second question now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem isn't actually that you specify `Parent__r`. Rather it is that your `Parent__r` value specifies `Children__r` as a `List<SObject>`.

Serialize a query result which includes a [`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join) and look more closely. The child relationship key doesn't point to a `List<SObject>`. It points to a `Map<String, Object>`. That map must specify both `totalSize` and `done` in addition to `records`.

Won't work:

```
{
    "Children__r": [{
        "SomeField": "some value"
    }, {
        "SomeField": "some value"
    }]
}
```

Will work:

```
{
    "Children__r": {
        "totalSize": 123,
        "done": true,
        "records": [{
            "SomeField": "some value"
        }, {
            "SomeField": "some value"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks. Probably this is the reason. I would expect Salesforce to handle this automatically. I don't remember the code I actually had, if I had something like 

SObject b = [ select Name, (select lookupToB__c from children_C__r ];

JSON.deserialize( JSON.serialize( new CustomObject__c(
lookupToB__c = b.Id, lookupToB__r = b ), CustomObject__c.class ); I wonder if Salesforce would handle that. Otherwise if I was populating manually JSON that you are right.

Answer (score 7):

A little late to the game, but for anybody finding this thread, I ran accross the same error, because the retrieval of a subquery through a @RemoteAction produces the incorrect structure as Adrian states:

```
{
  "Children__r": [{
    "SomeField": "some value"
  }, {
    "SomeField": "some value"
  }]
}
```

Therefore, if you are using this javascript object to Apex for deserialization through another @RemoteAction, you can "rewrite" it using a javascript function before sending it off:

```
function rewriteSubquery(array) {
    if (array && !array.hasOwnProperty('records')) {
        var tempArray = array;
        array = {
            totalSize: tempArray.length,
            done: true,
            records: tempArray
        }
    }
    return array;
};
```

As an example, if you have an object stored in Javascript, with the following structure:

```
parentObject = {
    Id: 'a0K0E000002AolHUAS',
    Name: 'Test',
    SubqueryObjects__r: []
}
```

You can then call the method like this:

```
parentObject.SubqueryObjects__r = rewriteSubquery(parentObject.SubqueryObjects__r);
```

Which will return the structure that you need for correct deserialization:

```
parentObject = {
    Id: 'a0K0E000002AolHUAS',
    Name: 'Test',
    SubqueryObjects__r: {
        totalSize: <array_size>
        done: true,
        records: []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we remove *lookupToB__r* from the json, the issue is gone

```
{
    "lookupToB__c": "bbb000000-id"
}
```

However, I am not sure if there is more elegant solution