# Invalid character in identifier

Tags: apex, json, compile-error, parser

I am getting an error on my JSON2Apex class:

```
Error:(7, 18) Invalid character in identifier: Holding_to_Fund__r
Error:(44, 19) Invalid character in identifier: Holding_to_Fund__c
```

I need to parse through some json that has a couple layers but the parser class can't save. Is there a way around the issue it has with the '__r' and '__c'?

I've looked at this answer [Invalid character in identifier in Wrapper class](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/246959/invalid-character-in-identifier-in-wrapper-class) and am curious if there is another way around renaming the objects?

Is it possible to just parse through it with the JSON parser class?

this is the JSON:

```
{  
"Id":"000000000000000",
"Name":"TEST 2",
"Comfortable_with_the_Following_Risk_Req__c":"Lower risk, lower return",
"Currently_Invested_In_the_Following_Req__c":"Real estate syndications",
"Holdings__r":[  
   {  
      "Investor__c":"000000000000000",
      "Id":"000000000000000",
      "Name":"000000000000000",
      "RecordTypeId":"000000000000000",
      "Holding_to_Fund__c":"000000000000000",
      "RecordType":{  
         "DeveloperName":"Fund",
         "Id":"000000000000000"
      },
      "Holding_to_Fund__r":{  
         "RecordTypeId":"000000000000000",
         "Name":"Test, LLC",
         "Id":"000000000000000",
         "RecordType":{  
            "DeveloperName":"Fund_new",
            "Id":"000000000000000"
          }
      }
   }
],
"ShippingCity":"","ShippingPostalCode":"",
"done":true,
"totalSize":123,
"Street_Req__c":"",
"City_Req__c":"",
"State_Req__c":"", 
"Zip_Req__c":"",
"Country_Req__c":""
}
```

JS that compiles the jsonString:

```
    acct.Comfortable_with_the_Following_Risk_Req__c = component.find('Comfortable_with_the_Following_Risk').get('v.value');
    acct.Holdings__r.Estimated_Appreciation_to_Date__c = component.find('Estimated_Appreciation_to_Date').get('v.value');
    acct.Holdings__r.Estimated_Appreciation_to_Date_Percent__c = component.find('Estimated_Appreciation_to_Date_Percent').get('v.value');
    acct.Holdings__r.done = 'true';
    acct.Holdings__r.totalSize = '123';
    var acctStr = JSON.stringify(acct); //this does not bring over done or totalsize
    var action = component.get('c.saveAccount');
    console.log('acctStr: ' , acctStr);
    action.setParams({
        acctString:acctStr
    });
```

Comment: Why are you using a custom class for deserialization? Just deserialize directly into the `SObject` record. See also: [Reading and writing child relationships of not-yet persisted SObjects?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/172925/2995)

Comment: I was getting this error when I just deserialize: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149574/salesforce-queryresult-must-start-with so I thought a wrapper might be easier. but it is turning out to not be

Comment: Did you look at my answer about the `done` and `totalSize` properties?

Comment: I did but the json string is already being passed to me so I would have to take apart and add in the two fields and then re-serialize and then deserialize. So it seemed again more work then just simply JSON parser class. Unless I am overcomplicating it?

Comment: Where is it being passed from? Do you have any control at all over the structure?

Comment: I do a little bit, when I add the two fields in I still get the same error. I updated the post with the two fields. I am not sure what the point of "done" and "total size" is. should I be taking these object names literally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child related list will not load properly unless you specify `done` and `totalSize` attributes. I explain why [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/172930/2995), but just to reiterate:

> - If you do not specify `done = true`, you will get an error:
>     System.QueryException: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop
> - If you do not specify `totalSize`, none of the records will get added to the collection and you will again wind up with an empty child list!

So, your JSON structure needs to look like:

```
{
    "Id":"000000000000000",
    "Name":"TEST 2",
    "Comfortable_with_the_Following_Risk_Req__c":"Lower risk, lower return",
    "Currently_Invested_In_the_Following_Req__c":"Real estate syndications",
    "Holdings__r": [{
        "totalSize": 2,
        "done": true,
        "Investor__c": "...",
        ...
    }],
    ...
}
```

Comment: this did not work for me. but I did find a way around it. I would suggest using the way Adrian details out here if you can get it working. For me I saved the values I needed from Holdings__c object and then null out the Holdings__r relationship before stringifying the json. This allowed me to deserialize the objects in Account without the `__r` and `__c`